# How to find Min and Max value of xml element

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Can anyone help me with this problem?

I have to find the Min and Max months according to expenses values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shop>
   <month>Jan</month>
   <expense>2520,50€</expense>
   <month>Feb</month>
   <expense>2900,00€</expense>
   <month>Mar</month>
   <expense>1000,00€</expense>
   <month>Apr</month>
   <expense>1520,00€</expense>
   <month>May</month>
   <expense>500,00€</expense>
   <month>Jun</month>
   <expense>1250,50€</expense>
   <month>Jul</month>
   <expense>300,00€</expense>
   <month>Aug</month>
   <expense>0,00€</expense>
 </shop>
```

I already tried with XPath but without success...

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("XML/despesas.xml");

XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//shop/expense[not(. <=../preceding-sibling::expense) and not(. <=../following-sibling::expense)]");
int min = Convert.ToInt32(node.Value);
```

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "without success". Did you get any error messages? If so, please post them here. If there were no errors, how exactly does the result differ from your expectations?

Comment: I don't understand why you expect the given XPath expression to identify the node with the minimum value; doesn't it only compare the current node to the adjacent ones, and not all of them? Please provide a [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: @moveaway00 No error messages... but also no results.. it didn't do anything...

Comment: @PeterDuniho XPath seemed a more elegant solution... With just one expression I would get what I wanted. I was trying to reproduce this exercise: https://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/xml-find-max-and-min-value-in-a-attribute-using-xpath-and-linq/

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner and thank you for all your answers. I had exams...

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the xml, then find the Min/Max of the expenses and the corresponding month.

Here is one `O(n)` way to find the Month with Min/Max expense.

```
var xmlString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourDirectory\YourFile.xml");

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var months = xDoc.Descendants("month");
var expenses = xDoc.Descendants("expense");

var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

decimal maxExp = decimal.MinValue;
decimal minExp = decimal.MaxValue;
string maxExpMonth = string.Empty; //=> "Feb"
string minExpMonth = string.Empty; //=> "Aug"
for (int i = 0; i < expenses.Count(); i++)
{
    var exp = decimal.Parse(expenses.ElementAt(i).Value, NumberStyles.Currency, cultureInfo);
    if (exp > maxExp)
    {
        maxExp = exp;
        maxExpMonth = months.ElementAt(i).Value;
    }
    if (exp < minExp)
    {
        minExp = exp;
        minExpMonth = months.ElementAt(i).Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had written a solution but yours is better than mine :) I will try it.

Comment: @student I remember I had tested this code with your xml and it worked fine. Try it and see if it serves your purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

You could XElement and then getall the expense elements. To get just the interger value, you would need to remove the currency symbol as shown below.

```
var parsedXml = XElement.Parse(xmlToParse);
var expenses = (from e1 in parsedXml.Elements("expense")
                select int.Parse(Regex.Replace(e1.Value,"[^0-9]", string.Empty))).ToList();
var minValue = expenses.Min();
var maxValue =  expenses.Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using XPath, I suggest to use [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). You can then parse the elements into memory and query them a lot better. You can use the following sample to get the min and the max values:

```
void Main()
{
    const string content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + 
                                "<shop>" + 
                                   "<month>Jan</month>" + 
                                   "<expense>2520,50€</expense>" + 
                                   "<month>Feb</month>" + 
                                   "<expense>2900,00€</expense>" + 
                                   "<month>Mar</month>" + 
                                   "<expense>1000,00€</expense>" + 
                                   "<month>Apr</month>" + 
                                   "<expense>1520,00€</expense>" + 
                                   "<month>May</month>" + 
                                   "<expense>500,00€</expense>" + 
                                   "<month>Jun</month>" + 
                                   "<expense>1250,50€</expense>" + 
                                   "<month>Jul</month>" + 
                                   "<expense>300,00€</expense>" + 
                                   "<month>Aug</month>" + 
                                   "<expense>0,00€</expense>" + 
                                 "</shop>";
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(content);
    var elements = doc.Element("shop")  // Element shop
                        .Elements()     // All elements under shop
                        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Element = x }) // Get index for grouping
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2)  // Group by index so that month and expense element are contained in a group
                        .Select(x => new { Month = x.ElementAt(0).Element.Value, Expense = decimal.Parse(x.ElementAt(1).Element.Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any) })    // Parse into anonymous type
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Expense)    // Order by expense
                        .ToArray(); // Execute query
    var min = elements.FirstOrDefault();
    var max = elements.LastOrDefault();
}
```

At the beginning, you load the XML into an XDocument. In this sample, I parse the string, but you can also use the `Load` method to read a file.

The query is a bit complicated; first, you get all the elements under `shop`. You then select them into an anonymous type that also contains the index of the element. The index is used to build groups that contain month and expense.

Then, a new anonymous type is created that contains both month and expense (as a decimal) in a single object. Please note that parsing the value of expense into a decimal is culture dependent. In the sample, I do not specify a culture, but this might be required in a real world scenario. The resulting list is sorted by `Expense` in ascending order.

By using `FirstOrDefault` and `LastOrDefault` respectively, you can retrieve the min and max values.

Comment: I was really looking for an XPath solution out of curiosity. In my idea XPath would have a simpler code. What you think of this: https://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/xml-find-max-and-min-value-in-a-attribute-using-xpath-and-linq/

Comment: @student of course this looks very simple. However, the complexity in your sample is related to the structure of the XML. It would be much easier, if there was a parent node that groups `month` and `expense`. The complexity is related to the flat structure of these elements. So also an XPath expression would be very complex - and I doubt that it is easier to unterstand and to maintain than the Linq to XML query.